# Putting a group within a group [123[a-u]]

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm having a lot more difficulty than I anticipated in creating a simple regex to match any specific characters, including a range of characters from the alphabet.

I've been playing with regex101 for a while now, but every combination seems to result in no matches.

Example expression:
`[\n\r\t\s\(\)-]`

Preferred expression:
`[[a-z][a-Z]\n\r\t\s\(\)-]`

Example input:
`(123) 241()-127()()() abc ((((((((`

Ideally the expression will capture every character except the digits

I know I could always manually input "abcdefgh".... but there has to be an easier way. I also know there are easier ways to capture numbers only, but there are some special characters and letters which I may eventually need to include as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlooked a pretty small character. The term I was looking for was "Alternative" apparently.

`[\r\t\n]|[a-z]` with the missing element being the `|` character. This will allow it to match anything from the first group, and then continue on to match the second group.

At least that's my conclusion when testing this specific example.

Answer (score 1):

With regex you can set the regex expression to trigger on a range of characters like in your above example `[a-z]` that will capture any letter in the alphabet that is between a and z. To trigger on more than one character you can add a "+" to it or, if you want to limit the number of characters captured you can use `{n}` where n is the number of characters you want to capture. So, `[a-z]+` is one or more and `[a-z]{4}` would match on the first four characters between a and z.

Comment: Sorry, my question probably wasn't clear enough. I wasn't looking how to match multiple characters in a row, but more on how I could create the expression to be like [123abcdefghi] without having to manually type in the alphabet. I believe I found the answer to my question somewhere else, which was an "alternative" `|` character.

Comment: Yeah you can use the pipe `|` as an or in regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use partial intervals. For example, `[a-j]` will match all characters from `a` to `j`. So, `[a-j]{2}` for string `a6b7cd` will match only `cd`. Also you can use these intervals several times within same group like this: `[a-j4-6]{4}`. This regex will match `ab44` but not `ab47`